# Lista encadeada não está removendo os elementos

Tags: java, lista, estrutura-de-dados

Não consigo remover elementos da lista.

```
class no {

    public int dado;
    public no prox;
}

class lista {

    no ini;
    no fim;

    public void crialista() {

        ini = null;
        fim = null;
    }

    public void inserir(int num) {
        no novo = new no();
        novo.dado = num;
        novo.prox = null;

        if (ini == null) {
            ini = novo;
        } else {
            fim.prox = novo;
        }
        fim = novo;
    }

    public void imp() {
        no x = ini;
        while (x != null) {
            System.out.println(x.dado);
            x = x.prox;
        }
    }

    public void remover(int num){


    no ant = null;
    no aux = ini;

    do {
    if (aux.dado== num )    
    {
    ant.prox= ant.prox;
    }

    ant = aux;
    aux = aux.prox;
} while (aux!=null);



}

public  class Teste {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        lista lst = new lista();
        lst.crialista();
        lst.inserir(15);
        lst.inserir(8);
        lst.imp();
        lst.remover (8);
        lst.imp();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Não sei se é a causa mas isto: `ant.prox= ant.prox;` não me parece que seja/esteja correcto.

Comment: o programa da erro no método.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro vamos organizar o código, principalmente dando nomes mais significativos para ficar mais intuitivo o que estamos fazendo (pelo menos eliminar um nome genérico `aux` por `atual`). Aí fica fácil perceber o erro:

```
public void remover(int num){
    no ant = null;
    no atual = ini;
    do {
        if (atual.dado == num) ant.prox = atual.prox; //você tem que pegar o próximo do atual
        ant = atual;
        atual = atual.prox;
    } while (atual != null);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Xe8ADn). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/adzsxvkp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/LinkedList.cs).

Não estava mudando nada, é quase um erro de digitação. Isso acontece pelo código não ser muito legível. Muitas pessoas só entendem o poder da legibilidade quando começam ter esses problemas. Outras coisas poderiam ser ainda mais legíveis. Seria melhor que `ant` virasse `anterior` para favorecer a legibilidade.

Este código ainda tem problemas. Se a lista não tiver elementos dá problema, o ideal seria pelo menos verificar essa situaão antes de fazer qualquer operação. Provavelmente só invertendo o `do-while` para `while` já resolve. Claro que não haverá informação de falha, mas isso todo o código não está se preocupando.

Se é para fazer o ideal poderia ter um método de busca e o método de remoção chamaria esse de busca e só faria a remoção. A verificação se há elementos poderia ser feita por um método próprio, e assim por diante. Cada um com sua responsabilidade sem expor detalhes desnecessários.

Poderia inicializar a lista mesmo sem um método para isso.

Comment: Muito obrigado, estava quebrando a cabeça desde de sábado com isso, vou precisar ordenar os números quando eles forem impressos, consegue me dar uma dica?

Comment: Aí é outra pergunta. Tem algumas técnicas, comece pesquisando sobre ordenação de lista encadeada. É um pouco mais complicado, mas segue a linha da remoção. Uma das técnicas básicas é ir invertendo o `prox` do atual com o anterior conforme forme menor. (ou maior dependendo de como está fazendo).

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo, ajudou de mais.

Comment: Melhor que obrigado, é praticar o uso do site. Veja o [tour].